# Eclipse IDE an internal error occurred during: "Analysing projects". com/yakode/java/search/c

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, noclassdeffounderror, yakode

Getting `An internal error occurred during: "Analysing projects".
com/yakode/java/search/c` error window in eclipse after uninstalling **Yakode** plugin.

Eclipse workspace log in **.bak_0.log** from .metadata directory.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2019-12-08 08:12:11.783
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Analysing projects".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/yakode/java/search/c
    at com.yakode.java.search.b$3.run(SourceFile:209)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.yakode.java.eclipse (1036).
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:571)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:425)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:155)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:934)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.CompletionProposalComputerDescriptor.createComputer(CompletionProposalComputerDescriptor.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.CompletionProposalComputerDescriptor.getComputer(CompletionProposalComputerDescriptor.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.CompletionProposalComputerDescriptor.sessionStarted(CompletionProposalComputerDescriptor.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.CompletionProposalCategory.sessionStarted(CompletionProposalCategory.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.ContentAssistProcessor$CompletionListener.assistSessionStarted(ContentAssistProcessor.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.ContentAssistant.lambda$10(ContentAssistant.java:2509)
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$SingletonSet.forEach(Collections.java:4797)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.ContentAssistant.fireSessionBeginEvent(ContentAssistant.java:2506)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.ContentAssistant.prepareToShowCompletions(ContentAssistant.java:1853)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.ContentAssistant.showPossibleCompletions(ContentAssistant.java:1821)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitEditor$AdaptedSourceViewer.doOperation(CompilationUnitEditor.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.ContentAssistAction.lambda$0(ContentAssistAction.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.ContentAssistAction.run(ContentAssistAction.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:474)
    at org.eclipse.jface.commands.ActionHandler.execute(ActionHandler.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:95)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:487)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.executeCommand(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.press(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.processKeyEvent(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.filterKeySequenceBindings(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:443)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.access$2(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher$KeyDownFilter.handleEvent(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.filterEvent(Display.java:1199)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1056)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1081)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1066)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1108)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1104)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.wmKeyDown(Widget.java:1759)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_KEYDOWN(Control.java:5146)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.WM_KEYDOWN(Canvas.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4793)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:348)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4820)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3583)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1160)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1049)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:633)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:660)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1468)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1441)
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in com.yakode.java.eclipse.Activator.start() of bundle com.yakode.java.eclipse.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:863)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:791)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1015)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:117)
    ... 85 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientConnectionException: Connection is broken: "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out: 192.168.0.100:62946" [90067-199]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:617)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:427)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:194)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectServer(SessionRemote.java:435)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:348)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:169)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:148)
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:69)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:189)
    at com.j256.ormlite.jdbc.JdbcConnectionSource.makeConnection(JdbcConnectionSource.java:266)
    at com.j256.ormlite.jdbc.JdbcConnectionSource.getReadWriteConnection(JdbcConnectionSource.java:187)
    at com.j256.ormlite.table.TableUtils.doCreateTable(TableUtils.java:397)
    at com.j256.ormlite.table.TableUtils.doCreateTable(TableUtils.java:383)
    at com.j256.ormlite.table.TableUtils.createTableIfNotExists(TableUtils.java:100)
    at com.yakode.java.store.b.a(SourceFile:234)
    at com.yakode.java.eclipse.Activator.start(SourceFile:1220)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:842)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:554)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:834)
    ... 92 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:546)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:585)
    at org.h2.util.NetUtils.createSocket(NetUtils.java:103)
    at org.h2.util.NetUtils.createSocket(NetUtils.java:83)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.initTransfer(SessionRemote.java:115)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectServer(SessionRemote.java:431)
    ... 109 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository 4 1002 2019-12-08 08:16:20.112
!MESSAGE Unable to read repository at http://marketplace.eclipse.org/marketplace-client-intro?mpc_install=4708900.
!STACK 0
java.io.IOException: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/marketplace-client-intro?mpc_install=4708900 is not a valid repository location.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.SimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.load(SimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.factoryLoad(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:775)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor101.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.util.ReflectUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectUtil.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:409)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager$Metadata.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.updatechecker.UpdateChecker.getAvailableRepositories(UpdateChecker.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.updatechecker.UpdateChecker.checkForUpdates(UpdateChecker.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.updatechecker.UpdateChecker$UpdateCheckThread.run(UpdateChecker.java:78)
```

Can anybody help me to get ride of this issue?.

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message.

Comment: @greg-449 update question with log, Can you look into it once and help me.

Comment: This looks like two snippets from two log files instead of the log starting with `!SESSION`. Please delete or rename the `.log` file, reproduce the issue and attached the content of the recreated `.log` file. Obviously, Yakode has only been partially uninstalled, as you can see from the following line: `at com.yakode.java.eclipse.Activator.start(SourceFile:1220)`. It is unclear how you installed and uninstalled Yakode. Have a look at _Help > About Eclipse IDE: Installation Details_ tab _Installed Software_.

Comment: @howlger it works by uninstalling Yakode. I follow the steps you suggested. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To uninstall Yakode / any plugin from Eclipse, select all the plugin names available in the `Eclipse IDE Installation Details` window.

Follow the below steps to uninstall completely.

```
Help > About Eclipse IDE > Installation Details (Click on button) 
      > Installed Software (Tab) 
       > Yakode (Select Yakode related plugins/packages at the end you will find) 
        > Uninstall..(Click on Uninstall button)
         > After a while Restart window will come.. Click on the Restart button
```

Now you are not facing any **Internal Server error window popup Errors**.